# 'StackOverflowException was unhandled' errors in C#

Tags: c#, xna, stack-overflow, unhandled

I have a problem with my code. I finally got it so there were no errors, but now i have to deal with stackoverflow...

can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
    public Matrix Projection
    {
        get { return Projection; }
        protected set 
        {
            Projection = value;
            generateFrustum();
        }
    }
```

It would be nice if you could help!

thanks

Comment: More details please... add stack trace and the rest of the code

Comment: It is a recursive call, Projection calling Projection. Use a private field. Ruben's answer would work.

Comment: FYI, generateFrustum() should be named GenerateFrustum() according to the .NET guidelines: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx

Comment: @Nate pay attention to the comments to your questions and select an answer for each. It seems like most of your questions have been voted down due to low quality and you haven't selected a single answer or voted up any answers.

Answer (score 23):

Your set method calls itself: `Projection = value`.

```
private Matrix _projection = null;
public Matrix Projection
{
    get { return _projection; }
    protected set 
    {
        _projection = value;
        generateFrustum();
    }
}
```

When you use following form:

```
public Matrix Projection { get; set }
```

you don't need to specify variable to store actual value, but when you implement get or set explicitly you should declare additional variable and use it in get, set implementations.

Comment: Why did you add a bounty to a (simple) question that some else asked and you answered (correctly)?

Comment: Maybe someone will give better answer or more explanation on why there are different behaviours in this two cases (just "get; set" or with implementation of get or set).

Comment: public T PropA { get; set; } is sugar syntax for private T _PropA; public T PropA { get { return _PropA; } set { _PropA = value; } }

Comment: @DannyVarod Write that in an answer to collect your bounty.

Comment: @jonnyGold Done. Also added additional tips regarding calculations in setter.

Comment: @Ruben You've post a bounty.  Reasonable answer has been given.  What say you?

Comment: @DannyVarod Thank you for answer. Bounty is yours)

Comment: It's the rarest of badges.  Congrats.  I'm not going to complain about it as long as information was exchanged and questions were answered.

Answer (score 4):

You are defining an infinite recursion on your `get` and `set` functions.

```
get { return Projection; }
```

is equivalent to:

```
get { return get();}.
```

Answer (score 4):

Properties' setters and getters are implemented as methods (get_X and set_X).

Writing `Projection = value` within the Projection's setter, causes a recursive call to `set_Projection()` from within `set_Projection()`. (The same applies to `get_Projection()`.)

Since there is no condition surrounding the call, the recursion is infinite.

As for `public T PropA { get; set; }`, it is sugar syntax for:

```
private T _PropA;

public T PropA
{
    get
    {
        return _PropA;
    }
    set
    {
        _PropA = value;
    }
}
```

What you should do is:

```
private Matrix _projection;

public Matrix Projection
{
    get
    {
        return _projection;
    }
    protected set 
    {
        // Make sure that Matrix is a structure and not a class
        // override == and != operators in Matrix (and Equals and GetHashCode)
        // If Matrix has to be a class, use !_project.Equals(value) instead

        // Consider using an inaccurate compare here instead of == or Equals
        // so that calculation inaccuracies won't require recalculation

        if (_projection != value)
        {
            _projection = value;
            generateFrustum();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public T PropA { get; set; }
```

is actually syntax of

```
T _PropA; public T PropA { get { return _PropA; } set { _PropA = value; } }
```

So the answer will be

```
private Matrix _projection = null;
public Matrix Projection
{
    get { return _projection; }
    protected set 
    {
      _projection = value;
      generateFrustum();
    }
}
```

you can see read below examples for more info
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228503.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04(v=vs.80).aspx